# Inverse Gamma Prior with Scale Parameter set to 1

Tags: distributions, bayesian, estimation

\begin{align*}
X_{ij} \mid \mu_i , \sigma^2 & \sim N(\mu_i, \sigma^2) \nonumber \\
\mu_i & \sim N(\mu_0, \tau^2) \nonumber\\
% S_i^2 \mid \sigma^2 & \iid \chi_{n-1}^2/(n-1) \nonumber \\
\sigma^2 & \sim \textrm{inverse gamma}(a,b)
\end{align*}
In the above model, I am thinking of setting the scale parameter b equal to 1. One reason is that we then only have to estimate a. What are the problems and concerns in doing so? 
Thanks. 
    Hanna

Answer (score 1):

For a more detailed description of these models see Chapter 5 from the book:

> [Bayesian Data Analysis](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Bayesian-Analysis-Edition-Chapman-Statistical/dp/158488388X)

One of the problems with fixing the parameter $b=1$ is that the shape of the distribution of $\sigma^2$ is restricted which, in some cases, might be unrealistic or induce bias on the inference on the remaining parameters.

These kind of models can be easily implemented using BUGS or JAGS in a Bayesian framework and you do not need to restrict any of the parameter values. Also, the shape of the prior is updated with the information of the data, resulting in a posterior distribution of the variables. The book I mentioned presents some codes for doing so. See also:

> [Prior distributions for variance parameters in hierarchical models](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/taumain.pdf)